# How to search string character from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects below. This is the raw data

```
const data = [
  {id:1, sItem:"This is javascript", status:"trending"},
  {id:2, sItem:"javascript is fun", status:"trending"},
  {id:3, sItem:"learning javascript", status:"trending"},
  {id:4, sItem:"how to code in javascript", status:"trending"},
  {id:5, sItem:"javascript will rule", status:"trending"},
  {id:6, sItem:"javascript can do anything", status:"trending"}
]
```

And I want to search the **sItem** properties with the keyword **javascript**  and reorder them so that where ever *javascript* comes at the start of **sItem** that element should come first with index 0. Other objects starting with *javascript* should come next followed by the rest of the array objects.

**expected o/p**

```
const data = [
  {id:2, sItem:"javascript is fun", status:"trending"},
  {id:5, sItem:"javascript will rule", status:"trending"},
  {id:6, sItem:"javascript can do anything", status:"trending"},
  {id:1, sItem:"This is javascript", status:"trending"},
  {id:3, sItem:"learning javascript", status:"trending"}, 
  {id:4, sItem:"how to code in javascript", status:"trending"}
]
```

I have tried to filter array objects
`const search = "javascript" data.filter(obj => Object.values(obj).some(val => val.includes(search)))`

any suggestion will be useful.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want a little bit more? Your problem definition is not understandable. Input-output example also does not give away much information.

Comment: @gsan first object is the raw data and in that i want search with keyword "javascript" in sItem key and want to return the expected o/p as i have mentioned in question.
hope this resolve your doubt

Comment: if javascript come in starting of string in key sItem then want that object on the first index  then rest object

Answer (score 1):

This will separate out the 'javascript' ones from the rest, then alphabetically sort them all separately. Finally it combines it all into one new array.

```
[...data.reduce((b,a) => {
if (a.sItem.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase() == "javascript") b[0].push(a);
else b[1].push(a);
return b
}, [[],[]]).map(m => m.sort((a,b) => a.sItem.localeCompare(b.sItem)))]
```

The `[...data` will take the output and line it up as a single array. The `reduce(b,a` will separate out the javascript ones from the rest. The `.sort(a,b` will aphabetically order each of the 2 arrays (the ones with javascript as a first string and the rest.

```js
const data = [{id:1, sItem:"This is javascript", status:"trending"},{id:2, sItem:"javascript is fun", status:"trending"},{id:3, sItem:"learning javascript", status:"trending"},{id:4, sItem:"how to code in javascript", status:"trending"},{id:5, sItem:"javascript will rule", status:"trending"},{id:6, sItem:"javascript can do anything", status:"trending"}]

let neworder = [...data.reduce((b,a) => {
if (a.sItem.split(" ")[0].toLowerCase() == "javascript") b[0].push(a);
else b[1].push(a);
return b
}, [[],[]]).map(m => m.sort((a,b) => a.sItem.localeCompare(b.sItem)))]

console.log(neworder)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, loop over the items, validate if the string matches the term, and save into two arrays, one contains the strings that starts with the match and others only contains it, finally concat them to create the sorted arr.

```
const filterByKeyword = (arr, keyword) => {
  const [a, b] = [[], []];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   const el = arr[i];

   if (el.sItem.includes(keyword)) {
    if (el.sItem.startsWith(keyword)) a.push(arr[i]);
    else b.push(arr[i]);
   }
  }

 return [...a, ...b];
};

console.log(filterByKeyword(data, search));
```

Answer (score 0):

If this question is not very specific to JavaScript logic then may be u can use this light weight but fast npm package like **[ss-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ss-search)** to perform your search.

```
var ssSearch = require("ss-search")
const data =  [{id:2, sItem:"javascript is fun", status:"trending"},{id:5, sItem:"javascript will rule", status:"trending"},{id:6, sItem:"javascript can do anything", status:"trending"},{id:1, sItem:"This is javascript", status:"trending"},{id:3, sItem:"learning javascript", status:"trending"},{id:4, sItem:"how to code in javascript", status:"trending"}]
const searchKeys = ["sItem"] 
const searchText = "javascript"

const results = ssSearch.search(data, searchKeys, searchText)
console.log(results)
```

You may try the above code in [npm.runkit](https://npm.runkit.com/ss-search)